# Is Selenium Grid2 really capable to run tests in parallel on its own?

Tags: nunit, parallel-processing, selenium-grid

Well, StackOverFlow is such a good site, most of my google search results direct to here, really.

I've seen too many posts about selenium grid2 inside and outside this place, they all explained that, grid2 has such capability to run tests in parallel, how to set up grid hub and nodes. But, no one told me how to run tests through selenium grid2, all I got was "set up hub and nodes, then run tests, then all things become parallel". But how to trigger the running through selenium grid2?

Then, I got answers myself, that is, to trigger the running with another runner, e.g., NUnit. However, NUnit can only run tests serially, not parallelly. I've also tried other runners but they can't function so well along with grid2.

So I started to doubt, whether selenium grid2 really has such capability to run tests in parallel on its own? If so, how to? What is the whole workflow?

If not, then a third-party tool is needed to trigger the running, what's more, the third-party tool must be able to trigger multiple tests at one time(multi-thread, something like that?), so that grid2 can deliver those tests to its nodes to run them at the same time. In this way, can we call it a "parallel running".

What third-party tool would be a good choice? NAnt? Jenkins?

I have a long story coping with grid2 these days, these statements above are just part of it. If you can come up with anything, please tell me, that would be really appreciated.

我对自己的英文还是有信心的，在此多谢各位的帮忙了！谢谢！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium Grid 2 is capable of **executing tests in parallel** "provided you pass multiple commands simultaneously to the hub". You need to use a different framework like NUnit, testNG to run multiple test cases simultaneously. I use testNG for triggering multiple tests in parallel. It works absolutely fine without any issues. You can find some help on getting started [here](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, since I've already moved to another framework from another team, I give up my investigation for the moment. Thank you, A.J!

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

as descripted here:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Tests are passed to a node which executes.

Comment: Yes, I was doing exactly as you described(using WebDriver .NET version), I wrote that line of code right in [FixtureSetUp], however, when I run my test suite with NUnit, I can see it is running serially, not parallelly.

Comment: Best you add your whole "webdriver setup" code here. I'm java programmer and not used to .net but thats the best idea to figure out why it's not working. It should be running parallel tests and you don't need any more third party tools.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Coretek, but I still don't understand. Can you give me a code sample, please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid not, because I'm java programmer. Best you give me the procedure order and the code you use and I will have a look

Comment: Thank you very much, Coretek! I give up my trial for the moment and decided to use another framework from another team. Perhaps I'll start my investigation in the future.